# VueJS Reference to list

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

I just want to reference my timer to a list

```html
<div class="row row-cols-2 justify-content-md-center" v-else-if="timerData.length <= 4" style="height: 100vh; background: none">
  <div v-for="(t, index) in timerData" :key="t.name" class="col">
    <timer 
      :name="t.name"
      :start="t.start"
      :index="index"
      ref="timers"/> // It overwrite the old component
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to access like this:

```js
this.$refs.timers.forEach(e => {
  e.foo()
})
```

Comment: Try printing this.$refs.timers in your console and see if that's an array

Comment: Its a proxy. Proxy {timerClick: ƒ, gearClick: ƒ, …}

Comment: where is Event here in that object? Please paste the snap of  the entire object...Iam able to see only two attributes now

Comment: I think this.$refs.timers is only an array if you have the v-for on the actual elements you want to reference. Otherwise it will probably just reference the last timer in the loop. See here for details: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using template refs in Vue 3, which is slightly different than in Vue 2. In Vue 3, [using the `ref` in `v-for`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for) requires custom handling to collect the template refs in an array.

First, expose an array to the context:

```js
// App.vue
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const timers = ref([])
    return {
      timers
    }
  }
}
```

Then update the template ref binding to be a method that pushes the given element into the array:

```html
<timer :ref="el => timers.push(el)">
```

Then you can access the array like this:

```js
// App.vue
export default {
  setup() {
    //...

    return {
      callTimers() {
        timers.value.forEach(t => t.foo())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-template-refs-in-vfor?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 1):

I think this.$refs.timers is only an array if you have the v-for on the actual elements you want to reference. See here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

> When ref is used together with v-for, the ref you get will be an array containing the child components mirroring the data source.

```
<div class="row row-cols-2 justify-content-md-center" v-else-if="timerData.length <= 4" style="height: 100vh; background: none">
  <timer
    v-for="(t, index) in timerData"
    :key="t.name"
    :name="t.name"
    :start="t.start"
    :index="index"
    ref="timers"
    class="col" />
</div>
```